# Merge Duplicate Contacts

Tags: trigger, duplicate-management, upsert, insert, merge

So I have Salesforce system that was implemented 6 years ago and sits ontop of a extremely old sales system. When implemented it was built in a way that it creates duplicate contacts on different journeys.

There is a move to use Marketing Cloud but the duplicate Contacts could cause a consent issue, to remedy this we want to implement a system to prevent future duplication. 
Now the system is quite fleshed out and has allot of different insert points for new contacts. Writing a script to update the old contacts isn't an issue but to prevent future contacts from being inserted as duplicates I would like to implement some strict upsert rules at the DAL level.

So the idea will be to have a contact inserted at some point that looks like this

```
        Contact contactOne = new Contact(
                FirstName = 'FirstName',
                LastName = 'LastName',
                Birthdate = birthday,
                MobilePhone = '01234567891',
                Email = 'Test@One.com'
        );
```

Then the Id returned will be

> 0038E000019sV31QAE

And then at some point a second contact will get try to get inserted

```
    Contact contactTwo = new Contact(
            FirstName = 'FirstName',
            LastName = 'LastName',
            Birthdate = birthday,
            MobilePhone = '01234567891',
            Email = 'Test@One.com'
    );
```

On that second contact being inserted I would like to match on the key fields

- FirstName
- LastName
- Birthday
- MobilePhone or HomePhone
- Email

If these match then all other fields should be updated that are different and the original Id should be returned.

> 0038E000019sV31QAE

The issue I've got is I need this to be strongly enforced so not just if someone uses an upsert with this specified.

I'm currently trying to do this at the Trigger level for before update.

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after update, before update, after insert) {

    if (Trigger.IsInsert){
        for (Contact c : Trigger.new){
            List<Contact> matchedContact = [
                    SELECT  Id,
                            FirstName,
                            LastName,
                            Birthdate
                    FROM Contact
                    WHERE (
                            FirstName = :c.FirstName
                    ) AND (
                            LastName = :c.LastName
                    )
            ];

            if (matchedContact.size() > 0) {
                c.Id = matchedContact[0].Id;
            }
        }
    }
```

I understand this doesn't do all the matching and that using matchedContact[0] is not where I want to be but I'm just trying to get it to match and not insert the new contact and return the correct Id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use standard [duplicate management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5)?  You can use it in conjunction [with Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicates.htm#apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicates)

Comment: @DavidCheng The only thing I can see this doing is blocking the contact from being saved. The issue is I still need the details to be updated and then I want the original contacts Id to be passed back.

The biggest issue I am having is I can use the merge function which seems to be the correct way forward. I feel like this isn't the greatest solution though. What I may have to do is go through the older code and try to find where this gets entered and  create a DAL class for contacts that does this for me. 
The main issue is that there is a fair bit of spaghetti code from whomever wrote it.

Comment: You can set the duplicate rules to allow contact creation / update, but the findDuplicates Apex will still use the rules and return the possible duplicates, so your code can decide what to do from there.